# Variational Autoencoder loss is increasing

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, keras, convolution, autoencoder

This is my particular code for creating an abnormal convolutional autoencoder and my problem is the loss function is not able to converge to anything at all. I have tried different optimizers for computing the loss. is there anything that i am doing fundamentally wrong with my AutoEncoder?

```python
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Deconv2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (60000, 28, 28, 1))
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (10000, 28, 28, 1))
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
def base_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'encode_first', input_shape = (28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'encode_second'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'encode_third_downsample', strides = 2))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'encode_fourth'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'encode_fifth'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'encode_sixth_downsample', strides = 2))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Deconv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'decode_first'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Deconv2D(128, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'decode_second'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Deconv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'decode_fourth'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Deconv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', name = 'decode_fifth'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Conv2D(1, (28, 28), padding = 'same', name = 'final_layer'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.summary()
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
    return model

encoder = base_model()
encoder_hist = encoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=50,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

This is my output

```python
runfile('D:/Datasets/Siddhesh/Fraud Face/Face-Disguise-Dataset-master/autencoder.py', wdir='D:/Datasets/Siddhesh/Fraud Face/Face-Disguise-Dataset-master')
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
encode_first (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 64)        640       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_14 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
encode_second (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_15 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
encode_third_downsample (Con (None, 14, 14, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_16 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
encode_fourth (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_17 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
encode_fifth (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_18 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
encode_sixth_downsample (Con (None, 7, 7, 128)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_19 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
decode_first (Conv2DTranspos (None, 7, 7, 128)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_20 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
decode_second (Conv2DTranspo (None, 7, 7, 128)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_21 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_22 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
decode_fourth (Conv2DTranspo (None, 14, 14, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_23 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
decode_fifth (Conv2DTranspos (None, 14, 14, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_24 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling2 (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_25 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
final_layer (Conv2D)         (None, 28, 28, 1)         50177     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_26 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 899,585
Trainable params: 899,585
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 456s - loss: 0.3532 - val_loss: 0.2613
Epoch 2/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 438s - loss: 0.1636 - val_loss: 0.1176
Epoch 3/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 436s - loss: 1.9351 - val_loss: 2.1359
Epoch 4/50
60000/60000 [==============================] - 435s - loss: 2.1060 - val_loss: 2.1359
Epoch 5/50
16640/60000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 297s - loss: 2.1002Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loss function is increasing. The reason could be that you are using a very large learning-rate.